# Returning gzipped content on a Sinatra app

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails-3, web-services, sinatra, gzip

I have a Sinatra app inside a RoR3 app.

I defined a Sinatra module and added the following redirect in my RoR3 routes

```
match '/v2', MySinatraModule, :anchor=>false
```

My Sinatra app is serving all the services within /v2/* but they are not being gzipped.
I tried adding "use Rack:Deflater" in config.ru but since it passes through RoR3 it is not working. It is a json service, so it returns string.

I tried using GZip::ZLibWriter and it compresses the output, but is not interpreted as gzipped on the other side.

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's 2 things that come to mind to try.

Firstly, instead of using RoR as the router, let Rack handle it. There are several ways you could do this instead, the easiest is probably:

```
# config.ru
require 'sinatra_module'
require 'rails_app'

map "/" do
  run RailsApp
end

map "/v2" do
  use Rack::Deflater # you might want to put this in the Sinatra app.
  run MySinatraModule
end
```

The other thing you might try is setting the `Content-Encoding` header to `"gzip"`, or, if that doesn't work you could try setting the `Content-type` header to `"application/x-gzip"` (I'm much more dubious on changing the type header though). `Rack::Deflater` should handle that for you though.

Comment: And how can I start this server ? "rails s"?

Comment: @Tony Try `rackup config.ru`, or whichever paths to each of those things is.

Comment: I tried with rails s and it seems to work fine. Will it work on Heroku? I need to try.

Comment: @Tony should do as [Heroku uses the config.ru](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-support#rack-applications)  to run it as a Rack app. Glad you got it working BTW.